# Combinatorics: difference of permuted elements is constant

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

This is basically an equivalent problem of another problem, and I introduce the problem in this form as I think this is more generally understandable.

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $i, j$ be distinct elements among $S=\{0, 1, \cdots, p-1\}$, none of which are zero. Suppose there exists a permutation $\sigma : S \rightarrow S$ such that the following holds (from here all values are taken modulo $p$);

i) The value of $|\sigma(k+1)-\sigma(k)|$ is either $1$ or $j$ for all $k\in S$.

ii) The value of $|\sigma(k+i)-\sigma(k)|$ is either $1$ or $j$ for all $k\in S$.

My suggestion is that we either have two cases; that is,

i) $|\sigma(k+1)-\sigma(k)|=1$ and $|\sigma(k+i)-\sigma(k)|=j$ for all $k \in S$

ii) $|\sigma(k+1)-\sigma(k)|=j$ and $|\sigma(k+i)-\sigma(k)|=1$ for all $k \in S$

While the conclusion looks pretty intuitive, I'm stuck with how to prove it. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\sigma (k)$ is the element the $k$ value is permuted with right?

Comment: @MaxFt Yes it is.

Comment: Ok it is clear thanks  =)

Comment: $|\sigma (k+1)- \sigma(k)|$ take the same value for all $k$ or could it be a mix of 1 and j in your first i) hypothesis ?

Comment: @MaxFt It could be a mix of $1$ and $j$. More precisely, we have $|\sigma(k+1)-\sigma(k)| \in \{1, j\}$ for all $k \in S$.